# Multiple moving Graphics in Java JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, swing, object, graphics

I'm new enough to Java and I'm learning Game Design at the minute. I'm kind of at the beginning so its not a Game really.
I'm dealing with a single thread and an array of numbers.I have to get multiple square shapes moving around a screen at the same time. I have the code running fine for one square but run into trouble when I try implement it to multiple squares. I'm working with two Interfaces and I don't know how to use the Array to make multiple cases of a single random square. Any help would really be appreciated.
Cheers guys.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MovingSquares extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
    private static final Dimension WindowSize = new Dimension(600, 600);    
    private static final int NUMGAMEOBJECTS = 30;
    private GameObject[] GameObjectsArray = new GameObject[NUMGAMEOBJECTS];
    static int strtCoX = (int) (Math.random() * 600);
    static int strtCoY = (int) (Math.random() * 600);


    public MovingSquares() {
        this.setTitle("Crazy squares");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Dimension screensize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = screensize.width/2 - WindowSize.width/2;
        int y = screensize.height/2 - WindowSize.height/2;
        setBounds(x, y, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);
        setVisible(true);

        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();      
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
            GameObject.move();
            this.repaint();
        }   
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WindowSize.width, WindowSize.height);

        int size = 50;
        int R = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int G = (int) (Math.random() * 256);        
        int B = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        Color c = new Color(R, G, B);
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(strtCoX, strtCoY, size, size);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MovingSquares M = new MovingSquares();
    }
}
```

Second Interface - GameObject class.

```
import java.awt.*;

public class GameObject 
{
    private static double x;
    private static double y;
    private Color c;
    public static int ranCoX = (int) (Math.random() * 20);
    public static int ranCoY = (int) (Math.random() * 20);

    public GameObject() {
        int strtX = (int) x;
        int strtY = (int) y;
        int speedX = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int speedY = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    }

    public static void move() {
        int velX = (int) (Math.random() * ranCoX);
        int velY = (int) (Math.random() * ranCoY);

        if (MovingSquares.strtCoY > 600)
            MovingSquares.strtCoY = MovingSquares.strtCoY - 550;
        else if (MovingSquares.strtCoX > 600)
            MovingSquares.strtCoX = MovingSquares.strtCoX - 550;

        MovingSquares.strtCoX += velX;
        MovingSquares.strtCoY += velY;
    }

    public static void paint(Graphics g) {
        int size = 50;
        x = (Math.random() * 600);
        y = (Math.random() * 600);
        int R = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int G = (int) (Math.random() * 256);        
        int B = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        Color c = new Color(R, G, B);
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect((int)x, (int) y, size, size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: do not use a Thread to manipulate the position of the elements - but calculate their position whenever repainting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm learning about Threads and thats the way it was asked to be completed. running a single Thread for the objects (squares). The main problem is implementing my code into the given array.

Comment: BTW - the `repaint();` call needs to be ***on the Event Dispatch Thread***.  To put it back on the EDT, call it from `SwingUtiliities.invokeLater(..)`.  This kind of thing is automatic in a Swing `Timer` as suggested by @slartidan.  The main UI should also be constructed on the EDT (the stuff in `main(..)`).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version of Moving Squares that hopefully will help you understand how to do an animation.

[image: Crazy Squares]

One of the first things I did was to separate the classes into either a model class, a view class, or a controller class.  The [model / view / controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) helps to separate concerns.

Let's look at the revised version of your model class, the GameObject class.

```
package com.ggl.moving.squares;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class GameObject {

    private static final int size = 50;

    private double x;
    private double y;

    private double dx;
    private double dy;

    private int drawingWidth;

    public GameObject(int drawingWidth) {
        x = Math.random() * drawingWidth;
        y = Math.random() * drawingWidth;
        dx = Math.random() * 30D - 15D;
        dy = Math.random() * 30D - 15D;
        this.drawingWidth = drawingWidth;
    }

    public void move() {
        int lowerLimit = size;
        int upperLimit = drawingWidth - size;

        x += dx;
        if (x < lowerLimit) {
            x += upperLimit;
        } else if (x > upperLimit) {
            x -= upperLimit;
        }

        y += dy;
        if (y < lowerLimit) {
            y += upperLimit;
        } else if (y > upperLimit) {
            y -= upperLimit;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(generateRandomColor());
        g.fillRect((int) x, (int) y, size, size);
    }

    private Color generateRandomColor() {
        int R = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int G = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        int B = (int) (Math.random() * 256);
        Color c = new Color(R, G, B);
        return c;
    }
}
```

There's only one static field left, the size of the square.  Everything else is a dynamic variable or method.  This allows us to create more than one instance of the GameObject.

I changed the name of the drawing method from paint to draw.  This is so we don't get confused about which methods are Swing methods, and which methods are our methods.

We pass the width of the drawing panel into the constructor.  That way, we only have to define the width in one place.  You can see in the move method that we allow a margin the size of the square in the drawing area.

The constructor defines a random initial position and initial velocity.  Th move method merely keeps the square moving in a straight line.

Next, let's look at the revised version of your main class, the MovingSquares class.

```
package com.ggl.moving.squares;

import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MovingSquares implements Runnable {
    private static final int DRAWING_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int NUMGAMEOBJECTS = 30;
    private GameObject[] gameObjectsArray = new GameObject[NUMGAMEOBJECTS];

    private JFrame frame;

    private MovingPanel movingPanel;

    private ObjectsRunnable objectsRunnable;

    public MovingSquares() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            gameObjectsArray[i] = new GameObject(DRAWING_WIDTH);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Crazy squares");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                exitProcedure();
            }
        });

        movingPanel = new MovingPanel(gameObjectsArray, DRAWING_WIDTH);
        frame.add(movingPanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        objectsRunnable = new ObjectsRunnable(this, gameObjectsArray);
        new Thread(objectsRunnable).start();
    }

    private void exitProcedure() {
        objectsRunnable.setRunning(false);
        frame.dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void repaintMovingPanel() {
        movingPanel.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MovingSquares());
    }
}
```

We define the width of the drawing panel here, as well as an array to hold the game objects.

We start the Swing application on the [Event Dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by invoking the SwingUtilities invokeLater method.  A Swing application must always start on the EDT.

We create the game objects in the constructor and create the Swing components in the run method.  I moved the drawing panel into its own class, which we'll talk about later.

We use a window listener so we can stop the thread when we're done with the application.

We pack the JFrame.  The only place we're specifying a size is when we create the drawing panel.  We use a JFrame.  The only time you extend a Swing component, or any Java class, is when you want to override one of the methods.

Let's look at the drawing panel class, the MovingPanel class.

```
package com.ggl.moving.squares;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MovingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6291233936414618049L;

    private GameObject[] gameObjectsArray;

    public MovingPanel(GameObject[] gameObjectsArray, int width) {
        this.gameObjectsArray = gameObjectsArray;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, width));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        for (int i = 0; i < gameObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            gameObjectsArray[i].draw(g);
        }
    }

}
```

We override the paintComponent method to draw on the JPanel.  Since the game objects draw themselves, we call the draw method on each game object.

Finally, let's look at the animation runnable, the ObjectsRunnable class.

```
package com.ggl.moving.squares;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ObjectsRunnable implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean running;

    private GameObject[] gameObjectsArray;

    private MovingSquares movingSquares;

    public ObjectsRunnable(MovingSquares movingSquares,
            GameObject[] gameObjectsArray) {
        this.movingSquares = movingSquares;
        this.gameObjectsArray = gameObjectsArray;
        this.running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            updateObjects();
            xxx();
            sleep();
        }
    }

    private void updateObjects() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameObjectsArray.length; i++) {
            gameObjectsArray[i].move();
        }
    }

    private void xxx() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                movingSquares.repaintMovingPanel();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public synchronized void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }

}
```

This is a straightforward animation or game loop.  I put the repaint call in another SwingUtilities invokeLater method to ensure that the Swing components are updated on the EDT.

I hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: i like the layout you've put down. thanks for the help. It's a little more complicated than what I know now but I'll keep checking it as i update my knowledge. One question. my version has all the squares the same colour but i see in your screen shot theyre multiple colours, how have you accomplished that? Thanks again.

Comment: @cg-man: The colors are random as each object is drawn.  Look in the GameObject class at the generateRandomColor method.

Comment: Ahh i got it, my code is different to yours so changing it all wasn't sufficient but i noticed i wasnt refrencing the draw method at all, just repainting the same colour at different coordinates. Cheers Gilbert you're a star. :)

Answer (score 2):

Static variables will only be available once per Runtime. To create several `GameObject`s you have to avoid the `static` keywords.

Then call `new GameObject()` several times to create serveral instances of GameObject, each with its own set of variables.

---

edit:

1. move the variables `strtCoX` and `strtCoY` into `GameObject` (as suggested by @andrew-thomson )
2. fix all references to `strtCoX` and `strtCoY` inside of `GameObject`
3. change `g.fillRect(strtCoX, strtCoY, size, size);` to `for (GameObject currentObject : GameObjectsArray) g.fillRect(currentObject.strtCoX, currentObject.strtCoY, size, size);`

Explanation: The coordinate are attributes of GameObject. Each GameObject should have its own coordinates.

=> Your code should work just as before

4. remove all `static` keywords in `GameObject`
5. change `GameObject.move();` to `for (GameObject currentObject : GameObjectsArray) currentObject.move();`
6. initialize you GameObjectArray in `public MovingSquares()` constructor like this: `for (int i = 0; i < GameObjectsArray.length; i++) GameObjectsArray[i] = new GameObject();`

Explanation: with `new GameObject()` we are creating 30 instances (in that loop inside the constructor). Therefore we also have to call `move()` 30 times (and that is why that is also nested in a loop)

=> Wear sunglasses!

Comment: Further, the `move()` method of the `GameObject` class should not reference (or change) values from the `MovingSquares` class!  Instead each the`GameObject`  instances should only change their own values, which will then be used when the `paint(Graphics)` method of that `GameObject` is used (it never is, in that code).

Comment: Ok i see what you mean there but im not sure how i should call the GameObject class. every time i try it it says it cant call a non-static method or something like that. Please excuse my vagueness I'm only learning java. how would i incorporate the GameObjectsArray in the Moving Squares class?

Comment: @slartidan how do i call new GameObject() severla times?

Comment: @slartidan Thabks so much for your help i didn't know how to implement the Array but now i get the idea. cheers, great help.